# To Latin, what is the gender of an English word?

Tags: conjugation, gender, english

Suppose one writes, in English, a sentence in which some Latin is embedded, such as

> Eventually, they declared the rodent to be a squirrel *non grata* in their garden.

Of course this alludes to the diplomatic phrase "persona non grata", but suppose one wants to be pedantic about the Latin, even though one mainly is writing in English and the reader of English may not care.  How would one determine for which Latin gender to inflect *nón gráta*?

- Would one use the masculine gender of *sciúrus*, for "squirrel *nón grátus*"?
- Does it depend on the sex of the squirrel?
- What if there instead are multiple squirrels of different sexes? (I assume masculine plural would be used traditionally?)
- What if the thing not wanted in the garden is inanimate, such as a *rusting car*? ("squirrel", "rusting car", "garden", and the rest of the English example sentence are used only for example.)

Google isn't very helpful, because it wants to tell me about the gender of Latin words rather than of English words.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, it depends if you're writing in Latin or English! If you're writing in English, grammatical gender is generally not a concern, even with foreign words—just like we don't decline the words and declare someone *personam non gratam*, or talk about the status of a *personae non gratae*.

If you're inserting the English word "squirrel" into a Latin sentence, though, that's a good question—and one that may not be answerable, unfortunately. The vast majority of loanwords into Classical Latin came from languages with grammatical gender, or were put into a gender based on their semantics (e.g. a man's name would be masculine). I can't think of enough examples of loanwords specifically *assigned* an arbitrary gender by Classical speakers to derive a rule from them.

Comment: Apologies, I edited my question to clarify that I meant embedding Latin in an English sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure ["personae non gratae"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22personae+non+gratae%22) is unused in English.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's considered pretentious, but doesn't German often decline Latin nouns? It seems to me that English uses the nominative not because it's non-Latin but because it's non-inflected.

Comment: @brianpck Right; I'm saying we don't inflect the words for gender or case in English, because English doesn't have those features on nouns, but often do inflect them for number, which English does have (one alumnus, several alumni).

Comment: @user570286 As plural (which English has), not as genitive (which it doesn't, as an inflectional marking on nouns).

Comment: The iWeb corpus has the same number (2 each) of _dei ex machinis_ and _dei ex machinae_. The latter are presumably perpetrated by people who sort of know that Latin words in _-a_ form their plurals in _-ae_, but have no clue about Latin accidence.

Comment: @brianpck "Considered pretentious" is putting it mildly. Declining Latin nouns in German is very rare. Try telling a German "Im ausgeschalteten Statui verbraucht der Fernseher kaum Strom" and enjoy the look on his face ;-) But yes, historically, especially among *Altphilologen* (classical philologists), this was sometimes done.

Comment: @brianpck For number, German typically does inflect Latin nouns, but for case this is done only with a few names, and then nowadays only for the genitive ("zur Zeit Jesu", "auf dem Stuhle Petri"); for other cases, it is rather archaic (you'll find it almost exclusively in the lyrics of old hymns, such as "meinen Jesum lass' ich nicht").